# How do I set div height/width using screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My screen resolution is 2560 x 1440. If I want a divs height to be (for example) 10% of my vertical screen resolution (144px) how would I do this?

I'm guessing this must be done with javascript...?

EDIT:

`vw` and `vh` are not what I need.

I need the entire screen resolution of my computer not of just the browser window which is what `vw` and `vh` do.

The question this post is similar to does indeed show users how to detect screen resolution, BUT not specifically how to use that screen resolution to modify a div in CSS.

Figured it out on my own...

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("div").style.height = screen.height + "px";
</script>
```

Comment: There's always relative [viewport percentages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length). `vw` and `vh`. This isn't based off resolution but the viewport size.

Comment: @noahnu That's not what I want. I need the entire screen resolution of my computer not of just the browser window which is what `vw` and `vh` do.

Comment: @noahnu I do not know how to implement that javascript and that's what this question is asking for help with.

Comment: <script>
 document.getElementById("demo").style.width = screen.height + "px";
</script>

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by set the width and height by vh & vw CSS Units for example
   100vh = 100% of the height of viewport
   100vw = 100% of the width of viewport

or use the media query for example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) , screen and (min-height: 768px) {
    /* css for 1024px x 768px resolution and up */
}
```